# Curl post not working is my syntax correct for this post form?

Tags: curl

I have an html form that looks like below,

I am trying to post on this using Curl and the curl command that I am using looks like this, but the server isnt processing it and comes back to the same page, but if I do it via browser it passed and moves to next page.

Here is the curl commands that I tried.

```
 curl --data "email=myuser&password=mypass" http://someweb.com/login.php
```

And this the actual form that I am trying to post to.

Question, is the curl syntax I am using correct given the form below ??

```
        <form action='login.php' method='POST' name='login'>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type='text' class="form-control"  name='email' id='email' placeholder="Enter Username or Email Address">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name='password' id="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>


          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='persistent' id='persistent' value='1'> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green btn-2x">Submit</button>


  <noscript><input type='hidden' name='javascript_disabled' value='1' /></noscript>
     <input type='hidden' name='task' value='dologin' />
     <input type='hidden' name='return_url' value='http://someweb.com/' />

     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command line misses the checkbox named 'persistent' and the hidden input fields named 'task' and  'return_url'. Note that you need to URL encode them too.

Comment: Thanks I have tried other input fields too but still failing. what is url encoding exactly perhaps that's the issue